# How to import text from a webpage into a textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I get text from a basic HTML page and show it in a TextView.

I want to do it this way because it will look better than having a webview showing the text.

There is only one line on the html page. I can change it to a txt file if needed.

Could you also provide a quick example?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to download the HTML first using something like [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to retrieve the data from the Internet (assuming you need to get it from the Internet and not a local file).  Once you've done that, you can either display the HTML in a WebView, like you said, or, if the HTML is not complex and contains nothing other than some basic tags (`<a>`, `<img>`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<br>`, `<p>`, etc), you can pass it straight to the `TextView` since it supports some basic HTML display.

To do this, you simply call [`Html.fromHtml`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29), and pass it your downloaded HTML string.  For example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyTextview);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString));
```

The `fromHtml` method will parse the HTML and apply some basic formatting, returning a [`Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) object which can then be passed straight to `TextView`'s `setText` method.  It even supports links and image tags (for images, though, you'll need to implement an [`ImageGetter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html) to actually provide the respective Drawables).  But I don't believe it supports CSS or inline styles.

### How to download the HTML:

myHtmlString in the snippet above needs to contain the actual HTML markup, which of course you must obtain from somewhere. You can do this using HttpClient.

```
private String getHtml(String url)
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line + '\n');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle exception (no data connectivity, 404, etc)
        return "Error: " + e.toString();
    }
}
```

It's not enough to just use that code, however, since it should really be done on a separate thread (in fact, Android might flat out refuse to make a network connection on the UI thread.  Take a look at AsyncTasks for more information on that.  You can find some documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) (scroll down a bit to "Using Asynctask").

Comment: Thanks, all I have is one <p> tag on the html document. Do I put the  URL of the HTML document where is says "myHtmlString"?

Comment: Nope, myHtmlString needs to be the actual HTML itself.  You'll need to obtain that somehow, such as by using the HttpClient class to make a network connection and download it.  Note that there are a few caveats... you must include the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your manifest so you can access the Internet, and you should do the network operation on a separate thread, so you don't block the UI thread while it's downloading.  I'll edit my answer to include a simple example of how to download HTML.

Comment: Can I just put an iframe in there so it would be <html><iframe>.............</iframe><html>??

Because I need this text to automatically update (As I change it on the html document.

Comment: TextView doesn't support the iframe tag.  To use it you'd need to implement a full blown WebView.  Even then, you'd still need to tell the WebView to reload the iframe when the content changes, it won't automatically do that for you.  But if you went down that route, you could simply reload the TextView's text by calling your getHtml method again.